Inverse of "subtend"
In terms of circles, I know that an arc subtends a corresponding angle. However, what is the proper terminology used when an angle encapsulates a corresponding arc of the circle?

"an angle is subtended by an arc.

"It is also sometimes said that an arc is intercepted or enclosed by that angle." -Wikipedia
One could say that an angle intercepts or encloses an arc. I find these both to be reasonable shorthand which respect both the mathematical and colloquial meanings of these words (although I suppose you could argue that referring to the rays defining the angle might be more precise).

Nice, so it seems that I can stick to using general words for this phenomenon.
